# Согласование и причастный оборот

Tags: согласование

Как правильно: «На одном из мероприятий, организованном» (по «одном») или «организованных (по «мероприятий») местным Домом культуры...»? Или можно и так, и так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Или можно и так, и так?

Не зная контекста, следует сказать, что **можно и так, и так…**

Пример контекста для единственного числа:

*В городе N мы выступали на многих мероприятиях. На одном из мероприятий, организованном местным Домом культуры...*

**P.S.**

А организатором других мероприятий, на которых "мы" побывали в этом городе,  Дом культуры не был. Да и провёл-то этот Дом культуры за последний год всего одно-единственное мероприятие — то, на которое нас и пригласили...

Answer (score 0):

Конечно же *организованных!* "Мероприятия" же во множественном числе, должно быть прямое согласование с ними. Ни в коем случае не по "одном".

Comment: Я понял фразу **в определённом** смысле, а упомянутый Славой контекст, конечно, вполне возможен, думал просто, что вы не это имеете в виду.